# How to do "nothing" in the else part of ternary operator

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I want to filter values of a list based on whether or not they are contained in some other list. If an element is in the list I will select it, else I want to skip it or basically do nothing.

Below is what I tried to do. How can I achieve this?

```
List<string> sheetNames = new List<string>() {"1","10"};
List<string> projects= new List<string>() {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};

IEnumerable<string> result =  
    sheetNames.Select(x => projects.Contains(x) 
                               ? x 
                               : /*Want to do nothing here */);
```

Comment: Why not use `Where` instead of `Select`? Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: Actually I didnt know that which is actually a much better way. Thanks!

Comment: Ternary operators can't "do nothing". You could just return a null string here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the common values from the two lists.

```
IEnumerable<string> commonValues = projects.Intersect(sheetNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> sheetNames = new List<string>() {"1","10"};
List<string> projects= new List<string>() {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};

IEnumerable<string> result = sheetNames.Where(x => projects.Contains(x));
```

Comment: That last `.Select` is redundant.

Comment: True. That was just copy paste mistake. forgot to remove. thanks for the info :)