# ? operator error in syntax, error in the else

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I have this in my class:

```
public delegate void OnTrue(String TestPassed);
public event OnTrue OnTrueEvent;

public delegate void OnFalse(String TestPassed);
public event OnFalse OnFalseEvent;
```

This is my `Do` method:

```
public void Do()
{
   bool found=false;
   string p ="";

   // some actions

   found ? (OnTrueEvent != null ? OnTrueEvent(p): ;) :(OnFalseEvent != null ? OnFalseEvent(p): ;);
}
```

The problem that if in line does not work.

Exploded it should be this:

```
if (found)
   if (OnFalseEvent != null)
      OnFalseEvent(p);
else
   if (OnTrueEvent != null)
      OnTrueEvent(p);
```

I would like to know where you are wrong and how correct it should be.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Why would you not use simple `if-else` blocks?

Comment: ';' it is not a valid terminator after ':' (I do not know what the correct translation is, I have visual studio in Italian)

Comment: `? :` is an *operator* which *must return* a value, that's why `: ;` is a *syntax error*

Comment: Just as a general advice - you are really abusing ternary operators here and sacrificing readability for a few lines of code is a really bad idea. I know it's not your question but I think you shld go with your "exploded" variant.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko yes but also without ';' however, by saying that ')' is not a valid terminator

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146905/do-nothing-when-other-side-of-ternary-operator-is-reached

Comment: Possible duplicate of [?: ?? Operators Instead Of IF|ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208067/operators-instead-of-ifelse)

Answer (score 4):

> exploded it should be this:

and there-in is the error; no, it shouldn't. The conditional operator is always an expression, not a statement. It has no defined meaning in the way you've used it.

If you mean `if`/`else`: use `if`/`else`.

Note that you *can* simplify some of the code, though:

```
(found ? OnFalseEvent : OnTrueEvent)?.Invoke(p);
```

This works because the conditional part is used *as an expression* - meaning: the value is consumed. In this case, it is *consumed* by the null-coalescing invoke.

Note that this would **only** work if `OnFalseEvent` and `OnTrueEvent` have the same delegate type, which they probably should. `Action<string>` would work fine. If they don't, you'll need the longer:

```
if(found)
    OnTrueEvent?.Invoke(p);
else
    OnFalseEvent?.Invoke(p);
```

(your choice of braces and indentation is left as an exercise for the reader)

Comment: Note that `?.Invoke(p)` would only work after C# 6.0.

Comment: @Nisarg As the current version is C#7.2, I guess it's ok to answer on C#6 level.

Comment: @RenéVogt I'm merely noting the fact so that OP isn't perplexed if that syntax doesn't work with VS 2012 or 13.

Answer (score 1):

As an aleternative for `null` checking you can assign the fields into *do nothing*:

```
public delegate void OnTrue(String TestPassed);
public event OnTrue OnTrueEvent = (item) => { }; // do nothing; not null

public delegate void OnFalse(String TestPassed);
public event OnFalse OnFalseEvent = (item) => { }; // do nothing; not null
```

...

```
public void Do() {
  ...

  // No need to check for null here
  if (found) 
    OnFalseEvent(p);
  else
    OnTrueEvent(p); 
}
```

Since `OnTrue` and `OnFalse` are *different types* you can't put it as

```
(found ? OnFalseEvent : OnTrueEvent)(p);
```

since `? :` must return the same type for both branches